# formData is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got a callback that uploads a file. Pretty standard:

```
function sendFile(file) {
    formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('photo[uploaded_image]', file)
    $.ajax({
      data: formData,
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/photos',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response) {
          console.log(`uploaded ${response.photo}`)
      },
      error: function(response) {
          console.log(`couldn't upload: ${response}.`)
      }
})
```

Why am I getting this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined

on line 2 of the function?

```
formData = new FormData()
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of strict mode/linter? Try `var formData = new FormData()`

Comment: Ah, that was it, thanks. Weird thing was this code worked as recently as yesterday.

Comment: If you enable `'use strict'`, attempting to assign a value to an undeclared variable throws a ReferenceError. Without `'use strict'`, the variable is automatically declared as global.

Comment: check your markup code. maybe does not exist "form" Tag.